# How are the pixel charges relate to two analog voltages for this CCD camera?

Tags: ccd, pixels

A CCD pixel area is represented as in the figure below:

[image]

And somehow in a CCD camera like [this one](https://www.teledyne-e2v.com/content/uploads/2014/02/doc0822D.pdf) each pixel converts the light upon it to charge. There are 1024 pixel elements in one of the model.

And inside the camera there are two 12-bit ADCs converting two analog voltage channels to digital.

But I don't understand how the light intensity on each 1024 pixels represented by only two analog signals(diagram shows two analog signals out of CCD). Can this relation be clarified in a simple manner?

Comment: "And somehow in a CCD camera like this one each pixel converts the light upon it to charge."  With (essentially) a plain old photodiode.  It's just that there's one per pixel (for both CCD devices and MUX devices).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ADCs so it processes two pixels at a time.

When two pixels are converted to digital, then next two pixels are converted to digital, and this continues until whole row of 1024 pixels is converted.

Then the same is done for the next and following rows until all rows are converted. Then the process starts all over from the first row again.

Comment: Oh you mean at the end there will be a matrix representing the light intensity?

Comment: Yes; AKA the raw image data.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental idea of a CCD is that an image is read out one pixel (or in this case two pixels) at a time by transferring charge across each pixel to an ADC. At the end of the row is a transimpedance amplifier and one or more ADCs.  You get one pixel per clock cycle per ADC. So with a 10 MHz ADC and 2 ADC channels you can read out 20 M pixels per cycle. if you have a 1024 x 1024 sensor, that would mean just under 20 fps.

Note however that CCDs are a relatively old-fashioned detector and are not very commonly used anymore, so most sensors you see will operate exactly like that. A more common approach is to put pixels in a grid and then address them using an X and a Y line similar to a DRAM cell. In this configuration the pixel is directly connected to the ADC and no charge transfer occurs.

Comment: The actual light detection is still the same, though.